# Java: Establishing correlations between type parameters

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

Assume that we have two generic Java interfaces: `Foo<T>` and `Bar<T>`, of which there may be many implementations. Now, assume that we want to store one of each in a single class, both using the same value for `T`, but keep the exact implementations typed:

```
public interface FooBar<T, TFoo extends Foo<T>, TBar extends Bar<T>> {
    TFoo getFoo();
    TBar getBar();
}
```

Above, `T` is used for the sole purpose of enforcing that `TFoo` and `TBar`'s classes use the same type parameter. Adding this type parameter to `FooBar` seems redundant for two reasons:

1. `FooBar` doesn't actually care about `T` at all.
2. Even if it did, `T` can be inferred from `TFoo` and `TBar`.

My question is therefore if there is a way to enforce conditions like this without cluttering up `FooBar`'s list of type parameters. Having to write `FooBar<String, StringFoo, StringBar>` instead of the *theoretically* equivalent `FooBar<StringFoo, StringBar>` looks ugly to me.

Comment: As a side note, I would love to see them adding syntax similar to `public interface <T> FooBar<TFoo extends Foo<T>, TBar extends Bar<T>> { }` to Java.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Not with `T` being generic. Great question +1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redundant generic parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684186/redundant-generic-parameters)

Comment: *Type inference* would solve this problem. So the generalized question is: When do we get type inference like in Scala, for example? In Scala there would probably be no need for an explicit type at all at the usage site. As for your comment, this is the way it is done in Scala. If you accepted other languages on the JVM to solve this problem, I'd post a sample. But of course, this does not solve the problem in the Java language.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no better way... The compiler needs the T type to be declared in order to use it and there is no other place to declare it :

EDIT : unrelated link

> If bound A is not specified first, you get a compile-time error:
>
> ```
>  class D <T extends B & A & C> { /* ... */ }  // compile-time error
> ```
>
> ([extract from this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html))

And this is a little out of the subject, but [this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) defines the conventions on type parameters names as being single, uppercase letters.

Comment: While I don't contest the point you're making, I would just like to point out for the record that the linked document doesn't seem to address anything similar to this. Also, your quote is talking about the ordering of classes and interfaces in bounds, not whether or not they've been declared.

Comment: You're right, the linked document is not primarily dedicated to the subject, hence presence of the quote (edited to make it a bit clearer). And, yes, ordering is mentionned, but what's the difference between `not specified first` and simply `not specified` ?

Comment: The point the doc is trying to get across is that classes have to be specified before interfaces in an extends statement. The quote may seem relevant when taken out of context, but in context it has nothing to do with this topic.

Comment: Oh, my bad ! And I can't seem to put my hands on good link... yet :)